# Difficulty binding iOS delegate method without parameters

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When binding a iOS lib.a for Xamarin, I'm getting the following error:

```
btouch: The delegate method Device.SomeDeviceDelegate.CaptureComplete needs to take at least one parameter (BI1003)
```

The bindings were generated [Objective Sharpie](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/objective_sharpie/).

```cs
namespace Device 
{   

    // @protocol SomeDeviceDelegate <NSObject>
    [Protocol, Model, Preserve]
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    interface SomeDeviceDelegate
    {
        // @optional -(void)CaptureComplete;
        [Export("CaptureComplete")]
        void CaptureComplete();
    }

    // @interface SomeDevice : NSObject
    [Protocol, Model, Preserve]
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject), Delegates = new[] { "WeakDelegate" }, Events = new[] { typeof(SomeDeviceDelegate) })]
    interface SomeDevice
    {
        [Wrap("WeakDelegate")]
        SomeDeviceDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

        // @property (assign, nonatomic) id<SomeDeviceDelegate> delegate;
        [NullAllowed, Export("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]
        SomeDeviceDelegate WeakDelegate { get; set; }
    }

}
```

*NB. I've changed the name to `SomeDevice` to hide the hardware/device name (NDA).*

The compiler is complaining that the `// @optional -(void)CaptureComplete;` and respective binding `CaptureComplete()` has no parameters and that it needs at least one.

**Q:** What do I need to do to bind this delegate?

I have tried the [Binding Types Reference Guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_types_reference_guide/) and have tried applying the

- `EventArgs` attribute
- `NoDefaultValue` attribute
- `DefaultValueFromArgument` attribute

**UPDATE**

I misunderstood the `NoDefaultValue` and `DefaultValueFromArgument` attributes, they are used when the delegate returns a value (e.g. `bool`) as the return interferes with the Xamarin wrapping of the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.

*NB: I haven't change the names this time as it made the answer less clear.*

The preferred way of handling ObjC delegate is to expose them as Events, e.g.

```
// @interface ICBarCodeReader : ICISMPDevice
[DisableDefaultCtor]
[BaseType(typeof(ICISMPDevice), Delegates = new[] { "WeakDelegate" }, Events = new[] { typeof(ICBarCodeReaderDelegate) }))]
public interface ICBarCodeReader
{
    [Wrap("WeakDelegate")]
    ICBarCodeReaderDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

    // @property (assign, nonatomic) id<ICISMPDeviceDelegate,ICBarCodeReaderDelegate> delegate;
    [NullAllowed, Export("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]
    ICBarCodeReaderDelegate WeakDelegate { get; set; }
}
```

The Delegate and Events parameter of BaseType, generates codes that wraps each method on the ICBarCodeReaderDelegate.

```
// @protocol ICBarCodeReaderDelegate
[Protocol, Model, Preserve]
[BaseType(typeof(ICISMPDeviceDelegate))]
public interface ICBarCodeReaderDelegate
{
    // @required -(void)barcodeData:(id)data ofType:(int)type;
    [Abstract]
    [Export("barcodeData:ofType:")]
    [EventArgs("BarcodeData")]
    void BarcodeData(string data, BarCodeSymbologies type);

    // @required -(void)configurationRequest;
    [Abstract]
    [Export("configurationRequest")]
    void ConfigurationRequest();
}
```

Which allows you in your project to do:

```
public void Init()
{
    _sharedBarCodeReader.BarcodeData += OnBarcodeData;
}

private void OnBarcodeData(object sender, BarcodeDataEventArgs e)
{
    var barcode = Convert.ToString(sender); // this maps to string data
    //BarCodeSymbologies is in BarcodeDataEventArgs

    var handler = BarCodeData;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, barcode);
}
```

However this approach fails when the method has no parameters, as told by the btouch error message.

The other approach that I only discovered (and now appears straight forward and simple) is not to wrap the delegate as  events, e.g.

```
// @interface ICBarCodeReader : ICISMPDevice
[DisableDefaultCtor]
[BaseType(typeof(ICISMPDevice))]
public interface ICBarCodeReader
{
    [Wrap("WeakDelegate")]
    ICBarCodeReaderDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

    // @property (assign, nonatomic) id<ICISMPDeviceDelegate,ICBarCodeReaderDelegate> delegate;
    [NullAllowed, Export("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]
    ICBarCodeReaderDelegate WeakDelegate { get; set; }
}
```

And instead create a implementation of the Delegate interface.

e.g.

```
public void Init()
{
    _sharedBarCodeReader.Delegate = new BarCodeReaderDelegate(this);
}

private class BarCodeReaderDelegate : ICBarCodeReaderDelegate
{
    public BarCodeReaderDelegate(BarCodeScanner barCodeScanner)
    {
        _barCodeScanner = barCodeScanner;
    }

    public override void BarcodeData(string data, BarCodeSymbologies type)
    {
        var handler = _barCodeScanner.BarCodeData;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, data);
    }

    public override void ConfigurationRequest() { }

    private readonly BarCodeScanner _barCodeScanner;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"CaptureComplete:" might be expecting a sender?

Comment: That is what I thought, however the ObjC signature doesn't suggest that it does. I tried adding a parameter to the managed method, however that generated another `registrar found a signature mismatch in the method` error further on.

Comment: I've added the `:` to the `[Export()]` and it now compiles.

Comment: This unfortunately fails at runtime with `ObjCRuntime.RuntimeException: Wrapper type 'Device.SomeDeviceDelegate' is missing its native ObjectiveC class 'SomeDeviceDelegate'.`

Comment: This wasn't the solution.